# How to build gradle for a new android project in command line

Tags: android, macos, gradle, command-line-interface

I'm trying to learn and understand how to use command-line for android development and I've been following the tutorial on the developer.android.com site http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html to try and create an Android Project from scratch in command line on mac with the following:

First I typed:

```
android list targets
```

Which displayed the following.

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-21"
     Name: Android 5.0.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 21
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
 ----------
id: 2 or "android-22"
     Name: Android 5.1.1
     Type: Platform
     API level: 22
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
----------
id: 3 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:22"
     Name: Google APIs
     Type: Add-On
     Vendor: Google Inc.
     Revision: 1
     Description: Android + Google APIs
     Based on Android 5.1.1 (API level 22)
     Libraries:
      * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
          API for USB Accessories
      * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
          Collection of video effects
      * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
          API for Google Maps
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : google_apis/x86
```

From there I had chosen `target-id` `2`

```
android create project --target 2 --name MyFirstApp \
--path ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity \
--package com.example.myfirstapp
```

I've managed to create the project successfully and now I'm trying to run the 'Hello World' app on a device. According to the instructions on the developer android site the next step is to use

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

to get gradle to build the project.

I've got both `Android/sdk/platform-tools` and `Android/sdk/tools` in the path.
I've tried this command line in a project that was created using Android Studio and it works with no problems. I'm wondering if I've missed a step

The error I get is

```
chmod: gradlew: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Does `gradlew` even exist before running `chmod`? You need `gradle` to generate `gradlew`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows How do I get `gradle` from command line into the project? The cli tutorial on developer.android doesn't mention a step prior to `chmod`

Comment: Download gradle from gradle.org.

Comment: I've downloaded gradle, unzipped it and put it in `~/Library/gradle` added the PATH to the `~/Library/gradle/bin` and in terminal checked I have access to gradle by typing `gradle --help` which works but when I run the command `chmod +x gradlew` I still get the same error message as OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an android project from the command line will not with the options above create the gradle wrapper (gradlew)

You need to use:

```
android create project --target 2 -g -v 1.0.0 --name MyFirstApp --path ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp
```

The -g specifies to create the gradle wrapper and -v which version of the gradle android plugin version.
Use `android --help create project` for help with this command

Comment: The `chmod +x gradlew` worked and then i followed this up with `./gradlew assembleDebug` and I got a `BUILD FAILED`

Comment: This builds with gradle android plugin 1.2.3: `android create project --target 2 -g -v 1.2.3 --name MyFirstApp --path ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp` I had to change gradle distibution url in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.propeties file to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip The final step was to change `runProguard false` to `minifyEnabled true` - The wrapper uses the distribution url to build the app which needed to be updated in line with the config created from the gradle plugin